# select elements from table C not paired with elements from table A in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've got

table stores      -> storeid

table store_items -> storeid, itemid

table items       -> itemid

I want to select items missing on each store. How can I get those?

So far I've got:

```
SELECT ts.storeid, ti.itemid
FROM stores ts,items ti
LEFT JOIN store_items tsi ON ts.storeid = tsi.storeid AND ti.itemid = tsi.itemid 
WHERE tsi.itemid IS NULL
```

but all I get is:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "ts.storeid" could not be bound.
```

Trying to remove the alias from the condition:

```
SELECT ts.storeid, ti.itemid
FROM stores ts,items ti
LEFT JOIN store_items tsi ON storeid = tsi.storeid AND ti.itemid = tsi.itemid 
WHERE tsi.itemid IS NULL
```

executes without error but gives me the same result set as using `ON ti.itemid = tsi.itemid` instead of `ON ts.storeid = tsi.storeid AND ti.itemid = tsi.itemid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix old style joins and explicit joins.  In fact, just follow a simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.

In this case, you want a `cross join`:

```
SELECT ts.storeid, ti.itemid
FROM stores ts cross join
     items ti left join
     store_items tsi
     ON ti.itemid = tsi.itemid and ts.storeid = tsi.storeid
WHERE tsi.itemid IS NULL;
```

The problem with the comma is the scoping rules that MySQL (and ANSI SQL) insists on.  The comma prevents the next part of the `from` clause from knowing about the aliases that occur in the first part.  The `cross join` fixes this problem.

Comment: Worked like a charm. No more comma style joins from now on :-) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
SELECT ts.storeid, ti.itemid
FROM stores ts, items ti
where not exists(
    select 1 from store_items tsi
    where
        tsi.itemid = ti.itemid and
        tsi.storeid = ts.storeid
)
order by ts.storeid, ti.itemid
```